# Object required in vba while assigning a range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub APnumbers()
Dim Currentcell As Range
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Activate
Set Currentcell = ActiveSheet.Range("BA5").Activate
End Sub
```

On second last line i am obtaining an error "Object required". Can you help?

Comment: I don't think you can use .Activate on a range. You should either remove it or change it to .Select (if you are working in VBA, selecting ranges is largely redundant and takes up processing time).

Comment: You don't need the .Activate - in fact, you very rarely need this at all. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Comment: `Set Currentcell = ActiveCell` or `Set Currentcell = Activesheet.Range("BA5")`

Answer (score 1):

As the comments from Dave and citizenkong suggest, you can do it differently without select and activate. Something like this should do the trick:

```
Sub APnumbers()

    Dim Currentcell As Range
    Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    Set Currentcell = ws.Range("BA5")

End Sub
```